# Column not updating after saving model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

After i set the column in migration like this :

`$table->enum('paidBy',['BANK TRANSFERT', 'CARD'])->default('BANK TRANSFERT');`

And added to my model :

```php
protected $fillable = ['paidBy'];
protected $visible = ['paidBy'];
```

I wanted to update the column for a model but it's not working :

```php
$ad->paidBy = 'CARD';
$ad->save();
```

How can i update it ?

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: There is no error message is just that the column isn't updating.

Comment: while the error is not clear , you need to do some debugging, make sure about the value of `$ad` is it returned as an instance of your Moded or not ? and then try to print the raw query that is executed out of your code , and execute it directly on your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i had a mutator for the column `paidBy` that i forgot to delete. Now it's working

Comment: okay. we could not know that ;-) But always good to check the model.

Answer (score 0):

A very common reason why it is not updated is that you forget to set the fillable in the model.

Put in the model you want to update: `protected $fillable = ['paidBy'];` 
in the model.

#### update

Then try to update withd update function: `$ad->update(['paidBy' => 'CARD']);`

Comment: I have it in my model.

Comment: @AbdoRabah Can you try `$ad->update([paidBy = 'CARD']);` for updateing?

Comment: `[paidBy = 'CARD']` doesn't look like valid PHP code/array

Comment: @brombeer You are right. i updated. thanks!

Comment: Change `=` to `=>` and you're good! ;)